# Mac perl script for recursive text replacement

Tags: php, macos, perl

I need to replace instances of the phrase include('file.php') to read require('file.php')
I tried using the following script, but to no avail. Is it because it has quotes? Some other reason? P.S. OSX 10.7.5

```
/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s/include('file.php')/require('file.php')/g" *.php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's because parentheses are metacharacters, they do grouping. You need to escape them with a backslash. Or easier, let `perl` do it with `quotemeta` function (also `\Q`):

```
/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s/\Qinclude('file.php')/require('file.php')/g" *.php
```